# i can't access my laravel development server using IP address

Tags: php, android, laravel

i'm trying to build an android app that requires interaction with a database server , i'm using my own computer for this purpose , i'm running wampserver 3.1.0 . i installed laravel successfully using composer , however when i type 192.168.1.6:8000/ to test i get a webpage displaying this error :

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://192.168.1.6:8000/

Connection to 192.168.1.6 failed.

The system returned: (110) Operation timed out

The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.

note that i already started the server using the "php artisan serve --host ipaddress" command , and the permissions in httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf are configured correctly .what confuses me is that when i type the same url in my phone browser it shows the laravel page with no errors whatsoever !!! , help would be much appreciated .

Comment: the outside world cant access your local IP(s)

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Might be a stupid question but as you didnt mention. Did you start/run the localhost wampserver and database?

Comment: yes , i forgot to mention that it works when i substitute the ipaddress with localhost in the url after of course starting the laravel development server at 127.0.0.1 , but i'm trying to get it to work using the ip address as it did work before in a previous project .

Comment: Are you only trying to access this from within your own local intranet?

Comment: yes , it works using my phone but not my computer for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe i failed to notice this but  i was using a hotspot shield integrated with my web browser which was blocking the connection the whole time .